# If $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous and $f(x)\neq x$ for all $x$, must it be true that $f(f(x))\neq x$ for all $x$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity, functional-equations

Let $f: \Bbb R → \Bbb R$ be a continuous function such that $f(x)=x$ has no real solution  . Then is it true that $f(f(x))=x$ also has no real solution ?

Comment: I think they mean it doesn't have a fixed point. For example, $f(x) = x^2 + 1$ implies $f(x) = x$ has no real solution.

Comment: @Easy He means a function $f$ so that the function $f(x) - x$ has no real zeros.

Comment: @ Arthur: You got it right.

Comment: $f(f(x))\not=f(x)\not=x$

Comment: @exploringnet: That doesn't work. Being not equal is not a transitive relation.

Comment: @FredrikMeyer $$f(a)\not=a$$ so, $$f(f(x)\not= f(x)$$ and also $$f(x)\not=x$$ so,from above 2 eq. $$f(f(x))\not=x$$

Comment: @exploringnet: Your "proof" doesn't use that this is a real function, nor that this is a function $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. So I can produce a counterexample by letting $f:S^1 \to S^1$ be defined by $f(e^{i\theta})=-e^{i(\theta)}$. Then $f$ has no fixed points, but $f(f(x))=x$ for all $x$.

Answer (score 30):

Since $f$ is continuous, saying that $f(x) = x$ has no solution means that either $f(x) < x$ for all $x$ or $f(x) > x$ for all $x$. Let's assume wlog that $f(x) > x$, then $f(f(x)) > f(x) > x$ for all $x$ so $f(f(x))=x$ has no solution either.

Answer (score 8):

Just a variation of the proof. Suppose $f(f(x))=x$. Define $g:x\mapsto f(x)-x$, which is continuous, and has $g(f(x))=f(f(x))-f(x)=-(f(x)-x)=-g(x)$. Then by the intermediate value theorem $g(y)=0$ for some $y$ in the closed interval bounded by $x$ and $f(x)$, and then of course $f(y)=y$.

Answer (score 7):

**Hint:** We know that $f(x)\neq x$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Without loss of generality, let's say that at $x_0\in\mathbb{R}$, we have that $f(x_0)<x_0$. Can it ever be the case that $f(x_1)>x_1$ for any other $x_1\in\mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 1):

If $f(f(c))=c$ and $f(c)=r$ then $f(r)=c$.
 
Since $c\neq r$ it follows that there is an $s$ between $r$ and $c$ such that $f(s)=s$ (in the case $c<r\Rightarrow f(r)-r=c-r>0$ and $f(c)-c=r-c<0$...) $\Rightarrow\Leftarrow$.