# Prove that $f(f(x))=x$ has no roots .... $f$ having a general form

Tags: functional-equations

This problem gave me some headache, especially because $f$ have its own general form :

let $f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$. Suppose that $f(x) = x$ has no real roots.

Show that equation $f(f(x))=x$ has also no real roots.

Comment: the same function with two definitions!

Comment: Well I think actually $f(x)=x$ is more an equation, not a definition for f

Comment: I thank you all, for your responses! I'm newbie, so I don't know on which basis I should give the choosen answer ....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider $g(x) = f(x)-x$. If $f$ is continuous, then $g$ will be continuous as well. A continuous function without zeroes is either strictly positive or strictly negative. This means that either $f(x)>x$ for all $x$ or $f(x)<x$ for all $x$.

Hence either $f(f(x))<f(x)<x$ for all $x$ or $f(f(x))>f(x)>x$ for all $x$. Either way, $f(f(x))\neq x$ for all $x$.

Comment: Why do you say must $f$ be strictly decreasing or strictly increasing?  This is wrong, since $f' = 2ax+b$ which must cross the $x$-axis if $a\ne 0$.

Comment: @MJD You are right, strictly increasing/decreasing is not the right terminology. What I mean to say is $f(x)>x$ for all $x$ or $f(x)<x$ for all $x$. Do you happen to know the correct terminology?

Comment: I think the way you have it now is perfectly clear.

Comment: After the second sentence, you could alternatively continue: $f(f(x))=x$ would imply $g(f(x))=-g(x)$, and the intermediate value theorem would give you a root of $g$ on the interval between $x$ and $f(x)$. See [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/370176/18880).

Answer (score 2):

let g(x)=f(x)-x, because f(x)=x has no real roots, then g(x)>0 or g(x)<0 for all x belongs to R.

suppose g(x)>0 for all x. then g(f(x))>0 for all x.

f(f(x))-x=f(f(x))-f(x)+f(x)-x=g(f(x))+g(x)>0 for all x

then f(f(x))-x>0 for all x, so f(f(x))=x also has no real roots.

the same proof for g(x)<0 for all x.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mbox{Id}_\mathbb{R}:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ the function $\mbox{Id}_\mathbb{R}(x)=x$. Note that :

- $\mbox{Im}(\mbox{id}_{\mathbb{R}})\supset \mbox{Im}(f)$,
- $\mbox{Im}(f)=\mbox{Im}(f|_{\mbox{id}_{\mathbb{R}}})\supset \mbox{Im}(f|_{\mbox{Im}(f)})=\mbox{Im}(f\circ f)$
- $\mbox{Im}(f\circ f-\mbox{id}_\mathbb{R})\supset\mbox{Im}(f|_{\mbox{id}_\mathbb{R}} -\mbox{id}_\mathbb{R})$.

Then if $f|_{\mbox{id}_\mathbb{R}} -\mbox{id}_\mathbb{R}$ no have real roots then $f\circ f-\mbox{id}_\mathbb{R}$ too no have real roots.

Answer (score 1):

This can be generalized to: If $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$ is a continuous function and $f(f(x))$ has a real fixed point then $f(x)$ has a real fixed point:

If $f(f(c))=c$ and $f(c)=r$ then $f(r)=c$.
 
If $c\neq r$ then there is an $s$ between $r$ and $c$ such that $f(s)=s$ (In the case $c<r\Rightarrow f(r)-r=c-r>0$ and $f(c)-c=r-c<0$...).

Comment: I appreciate your time and your explanation!

Comment: Nice. Might want to replace polynomials with continuous functions?