# Let $f(x)=ax^2 + bx + c$. Suppose $f(x)=x$ has no real roots. Show that the equation $f(f(x))=x$ has also no real solutions.

Tags: quadratics

> Let $f(x)=ax^2 + bx + c$. Suppose $f(x)=x$ has no real roots. Show that the equation $f(f(x))=x$ has also no real solutions.

---

One of the [solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/370167/1215260) found on this site goes like this:

> Since $f$ is continuous, saying that $f(x) = x$ has no solution means that either $f(x) < x$ for all $x$ or $f(x) > x$ for all $x$. Let's assume wlog that $f(x) > x$, then $f(f(x)) > f(x) > x$ for all $x$ so $f(f(x))=x$ has no solution either.

---

My doubt is, how did they conclude $f(f(x)) > f(x) > x$ from $f(x) > x$ ? Because $a> b \implies f(a)>f(b)$ only when $f$ is strictly increasing, but here we have a quadratic function which is of course not strictly increasing.

Comment: The assumption wlog is that $f(x)>x$ for all $x$. You can write it $f(y)>y$ for all $y$ to make this clear. So the same holds for $y = f(x)$.